# How remove all duplicated characters

Tags: java, regex

I've not fond a Regex sample working in Java  to remove all duplicated characters.

This code does not work well : 'g' and '<' are removed, more than two characters are not clearly reduced to one, and '454' is reducd to '5'.

```
s = "aa  hgjii2222 22    FFonn;;;,,1111111111 22< 454";
p = Pattern.compile("(.)(.)");
m = p.matcher(s);
System.out.println(m.replaceAll("$1") );
```

Output :

> a hji222  Fon;,11111 2 5

I've tried other solutions with less success.

Comment: Not all problems must be solved by regexps. Why don't you simply iterate through the characters, and only append the current character if it's different from the previous one?

Comment: no offensive, just wanna lol at the pattern `(.)(.)`. anyway, this pattern shrink each 2 characters pair to the first character.

Comment: @LiuYan刘研 just a kind thank for explanation!

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
String s= "aa  hgjii2222 22    FFonn;;;,,1111111111 22< 454";
s = s.replaceAll("(.)\\1+","$1");
```

The regex used is: `(.)\\1+`

```
(.)  - Matches any non-newline character and remembers it
\\1+ - One or more repetitions of the remembered character
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
"(.)\\1+"
```

instead.

The first symbol is repeated one or more times.

Answer (score 0):

That pattern doesn't do what you hope at all.

It finds **any character**, followed by **any character** (not necessarily the same as the first one), and then replaces this two character string with the first match (the first character).

In other words, it deletes every other character.

I don't think that a regex is the right tool for the job you're looking for; think about how this could be implemented as a FSA and it should be clear that regular languages don't describe the problem well at all.

It would be much simpler, and arguably clearer, to simply do this in code.  Keep a set of all the characters you've encountered so far, and remove any chars that match as you iterate - something like:

```
final Set<Character> charsSeen = new HashSet<Character>();
final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    if (!charsSeen.contains(c)) {
        out.append(c);
        charsSeen.add(c);
    }
}
return out.toString();
```

Comment: Thank for this point of view. Regex "(.)\\1+" is exactly the tool I needed. For uour purpose you can simplify (because Set return false if the value is already inserted) : if(charsSeen.add(c)) {out.append(c);} ..